# Name lookup on template base classes in non-dependent name scenarios

Tags: c++

Take the following code as an example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_base
{
    void doit(T*) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct foo : foo_base<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct get_result
{
    template <typename Result>
    static Result GetType(void (T::*)(Result*));

    using type = decltype(GetType(&T::doit));
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(typename get_result<foo<int>>::type).name() << '\n';
}
```

This code will fail to compile with both GCC and Clang, but succeeds with MSVC. The error clang gives is:

```
<source>:21:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GetType'
    using type = decltype(GetType(&T::doit));
                          ^
<source>:26:34: note: in instantiation of template class 'get_result<foo<int> >' requested here
    std::cout << typeid(typename get_result<foo<int>>::type).name() << '\n';
                                 ^
<source>:19:19: note: must qualify identifier to find this declaration in dependent base class
    static Result GetType(void (T::*)(Result*));
                  ^
```

Typically I'd side with GCC/Clang when it comes to conformance, particularly when they both agree, but I can't exactly reason about why. When `get_result<foo<int>>` is instantiated, it should also instantiate `foo_base<int>`, so I would think that the expression `T::doit` should compile without issues.

FWIW the workaround is rather trivial:

```
template <typename Type, typename Result>
static Result GetType(void (Type::*)(Result*));
```

Comment: Are you sure you're showing the correct code snippet? Can you provide a link to Coliru, Wandbox, or something like that?

Comment: Yes... Were you having issues when trying it out? https://godbolt.org/z/OcmyJ_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&foo<int>::doit` is actually `&foo_base<int>::doit`

so its type is `void (foo_base<int>::*)(int*)`, but `GetType` expects argument of type `void (foo<int>::*)(T*)` and so cannot deduce `T`.

Comment: Okay interesting. I'm now confused as to why `void (foo<int>::*ptr)(int*) = &foo<int>::doit` is valid, though.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I think I got it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: As there is a Pointer-to-member conversions (see [implicit_conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion))